# How to change the color of the sorting arrows in DataTables?

Tags: html, css, datatables

I am using `DataTables` and I need to change the color of the sorting arrows from the default (purplish) to something else. Code that I am trying is changing the entire header row color while I need just the icons.

Is there any other class because the below code is not helping me.

CSS

```css
table.dataTable thead .sorting, 
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc, 
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
   color : yellow;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. `DataTables` is using images for the icons so we cannot just change the color on fly. In order to do that we need to replace the icon images with the color of our choice. So in the below CSS, I simply replace the image from the DataTables with the one I needed.

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
background-image: url("../images/integration/upArrow.gif");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the colour of the sort icons in Datatables because those are **not icons** they are **PNG images**.
You need to override those CSS properties. *(DataTables 1.10)*

- Ascending

  ```css
  table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
      background-image: url("/YourImageFolder/sort_asc.png")
  }
  ```
- Descending

  ```css
  table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
      background-image: url("/YourImageFolder/sort_desc.png")
  }
  ```
- Both Disabled

  ```css
  table.dataTable thead .sorting {
      background-image: url("/YourImageFolder/sort_both.png")
  }
  ```
- Ascending Disabled

  ```css
  table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled {
      background-image: url("/YourImageFolder/sort_asc_disabled.png")
  }
  ```
- Descending Disabled

  ```css
  table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
      background-image: url("/YourImageFolder/sort_desc_disabled.png")
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap version of datatable then adding this css will do the needful

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after, 
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after, 
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after {
  color : yellow;
  opacity: 0.6 !important;
}
```

change color and opacity as per your need. Default opacity is 0.2 that makes the icon dull.